# Are Buckyball-sized black holes possible?

Tags: black-hole, singularity, molecules

The first item is the basic question; the subsequent items build upon it if it's possible.  If these need to be broken into separate questions, I can do that, but they're pretty tightly related.

1. Is a non-rotating negatively-charged singularity small enough to be contained by a C₆₀ Buckyball theoretically possible?
2. Would the charge repulsion of the carbon electrons be stronger than the gravitational attraction, keeping the singularity from consuming them?
3. Is it theoretically possible for a singularity to be too small to absorb hadrons or even elementary particles?
4. Anything this small would doubtless evaporate very quickly, but just how long *could* they last?

Thanks!

Comment: I think it all looks like an X & Y problem. Idea of getting canned BH isn't particularly good. Yeah, there's idea of something like that with antimatter, but it's already far-fetched. Another issue is that you shouldn't mix up concepts of singularity and black hole. BTW I think questions like that are more suitable for Physics.SE, or maybe Worldbuilding.SE - while the answer mentions, still quite big, primordial black holes, it's not like even smaller ones aren't *hypothetically* possible, but have more to do with physical speculation the astronomy.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

1. A buckyball is about a nanometre ($10^{-9}$ m) across. If you limit the charge on the black hole to something like that of an electron or a few electrons, then this would mean the event horizon(s) of a charged, spinless, [Reissner-Nordstrom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reissner%E2%80%93Nordstr%C3%B6m_metric) black hole would be almost indistinguishable from that of a Schwarzschild black hole. The mass of this black hole would therefore be around $r_s c^2/2G \simeq 10^{18}$ kg. Yes, this is theoretically possible and maybe such black holes [were produced](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primordial_black_hole) during the big bang and are still around today.
2. For Coulomb forces to outweigh gravitational forces then you need
   $$ \frac{Q^2}{4\pi \epsilon_0} > G M_{\rm BH}{m_C}\ .$$
   In this case $Q \sim 10^{-18}$ Coulombs, $M_{\rm BH}\sim 10^{18}$ kg, $m_C = 12\times 1.67\times 10^{-27}$ kg. The LHS is $\sim 10^{-26}$ Nm$^2$ and the RHS is $\sim 10^{-18}$ Nm$^2$. So perhaps surprisingly, gravity will win and the buckyball will almost instantly be incorporated into the black hole.
3. We don't have a theory governing the quantum behaviour of black holes. A singularity doesn't really have a size in a non-spinning black hole.
4. A $10^{18}$ kg black hole would evaporate via Hawking radiation in about $10^{30}$ years.

Comment: Thanks, @ProfRob, I was hoping you would answer.   You're so very informative.  So if I can get the RHS down, it's theoretically possible - but I'll have to do the math.  I couldn't find anything to determine the inside radius of a Buckyball, not impacting the cabin electron shells.  Wouldn't that matter?

Comment: "Yes, this is theoretically possible and maybe such black holes were produced during the big bang and are still around today." @user253751

Comment: Is there a reason you limited the charge to a few electrons? How would things change if you increased the charge to be sufficient for electromagnetism to win out over gravity?